# Subject Alternative Name must have scheme to be working in java?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I have an SSL certificate with SAN extension having domains like:

- foo.com
- bar.foo.com
- something.foo.com

I've added this certificate to cacerts and tried to connect to `bar.foo.com` using apache http client.
Unexpectedly I got exception:

`Unparseable SubjectAlternativeName extension due to java.io.IOException: URI name must include scheme:foo.com`

that lead me to `sun.security.x509.URIName` class line 112:
https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/x509/URIName.java#l112

```
if (uri.getScheme() == null) {
    throw new IOException("URI name must include scheme:" + name);
}
```

To me this means that SAN domains must have scheme before the actual domain to be valid. It appears it should be:

- https://foo.com
- https://bar.foo.com
- https://something.foo.com

and indeed, when I replace the domain while debugging code, all works ok!

So maybe the cert I got is not correct? I looked at Stackoverflow cert and what I see?
[image: StackOverflow cert]
SAN domains are also here without scheme so I guess those are correct.

When I then use cURL it also works perfectly fine so the cert is correct.

I found the following java bug records:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4834694
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4917253
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4834694

where people claim that indeed this is a bug but those records are 15 YEARS OLD - they are from 2003/2004.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong as it's impossible that java has this bug for so long

EDIT:
See that a similar bug appears when I use keytool to view the certificate:

```
keytool -list -keystore truststore.jks -v

(...)

#10: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
Unparseable SubjectAlternativeName extension due to
java.io.IOException: URI name must include scheme:foo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of SAN names. In TLS only `dnsName` name types are used (`ipAddress` are used much rarely). `dnsName` name type includes only domain part without any URI scheme.

The link you are referencing([URIName.java](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/x509/URIName.java)) is talking about another SAN name type, called `uriName` which indeed must include protocol scheme. This name type is commonly used to represent URLs to CRT/CRL/OCSP resources in certificates and CRLs. And `uriName` is not used for authentication. So you really need this name type: [DNSName.java](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/x509/DNSName.java)

Comment: That's not the case I think. I've edited my question and added info that keytool also fails

Comment: Ok, can you provide a dump of SAN extension? I posted my answer based on what you have provided in initial question. I can assume that your SAN is malformed. The textual dump of SAN extension will be helpful.

Comment: I had to change some letters but basically it's something like this
`0P..q-fth-sct.xqlav-fth.com..sct.xqlav.com..q-fth-sct.xqlav-fth.com..sct.xqlav.com` and the domain I'm calling using apache http is `sct.xqlav.com` and it fails with the exception I mentioned - the same that keytool throws

Comment: `sct.xqlav.com` does not exist (nxdomain) according to my ISP's DNS and also Google (8.8.8.8) Cloudfront (1.1.1.1) Level3 (4.2.2.1). If you have (or get) OpenSSL, `openssl s_client -connect host:443 -servername host` will display, among other things, your cert in PEM format (dash-BEGIN line, several lines of base64, dash-END line); add that to your Q and/or do `openssl x509 -noout -text <certPEMfile`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes this domain is not public. This was just an example

Comment: @bodziec do not use fake names for examples, this confuses everyone and does not help troubleshooting. `example.com` should be used for documenting examples (and not `foo.com` or anything else)... but of course then noone can troubleshoot things for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old one, but maybe it would help someone.

@bodziec - I don't know how you generated the certificate, but the follwoing worked for me:

1. This will generate a certificate and store it in the mykeystore.p12:

   > keytool -keystore mykeystore.p12 -storepass changeit -storetype PKCS12 -alias certAlias -validity 1234 -genkey -keyalg RSA -ext SAN=DNS:foo.com,DNS:bar.foo.com,DNS:something.foo.com
2. Verify that the certificate was created with the SAN info you
   wanted you can run:

   > keytool -list -keystore mykeystore.p12 -storepass changeit

   look for

```
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: foo.com
  DNSName: bar.foo.com
  DNSName: something.foo.com
]
```

3. To sign the certificate you will need to create a certificate sign
   request:

   > keytool -alias certAlias -certreq -keystore client.keystore.jks -file my_cert_sign_req.csr -storepass changeit
4. Sign certificates with your CA. This will require additional step of creating extension configuration file for openssl:

- create a new file: ext.conf
  paste the following and change req_distinguished_name and keyUsage.

```
[ req ]
default_bits       = 4096
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions    = req_ext

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default         = XX
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = default_great_place
localityName                = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = default_somecity
organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = your_org
commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max              = 64
commonName_default          = default_common-name

[req_ext]
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement, keyCertSign, cRLSign
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth,clientAuth, timeStamping
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = foo.com
DNS.2   = bar.foo.com
DNS.3   = something.foo.com
```

- Make sure you have you CA cert and key, then run:

> openssl x509 -req -CA cacert.pem -CAkey cakey.pem -in my_cert_sign_req.csr -out my_cert_sign_req.signed -days 1234 -CAcreateserial -extfile ../ext.conf -extensions 'req_ext'

5. Import the cacert and the signed cert to your keystore (make sure you set the alias of the signed cert to be the SAME as the original alias used when created the cert in step 1)

> keytool -import -keystore server.keystore.jks -storepass k1test1 -alias caroot  -file cacert.pem

> keytool -import -keystore server.keystore.jks -storepass k1test1 -alias certAlias -file my_cert_sign_req.signed